# Div background image full height on browser

Tags: html, css

I tried searching on google but i can't seem to find a solution to my problem which is that i like to make a background image which is part of the div to appear full size and cover the whole browser window. Moving the background image to the body element is not possible (constraint with the theme i am using) and i have tried using height:100% (which doesn't work) and height:100vh (which work but the background image extend more that is necessary.)

I have simplified the problem to something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="topmenu">menu</div>
    <div id="box1">
        <div id="box2">
            <div id="box3">
                <div id="homepage">
                    <div>text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

#homepage which is buried under several layers of div has the background image which i would like to extend full screen.

I have created a fiddle so that you will understand what i am talking about.

https://jsfiddle.net/6x08snnt/17/

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Percentage height is based off of the parent's height. If `html` has no height, `body {height: 100%;}` won't do anything.

In some browsers the body element has a margin as well, so let's reset that.

Assuming you want the two elements to fill the page, with no scrolling, you'll need to use `calc()` to combine a hard `px` value with the percentage.

```css
#topmenu {
  height: 16px;
  background-color:red;
}
#homepage {
  height: calc(100% - 16px);
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbqU-zynH0eweJzs4Kd6dQ0fkpr-eEUu_oHdv9Zd8w1-5vv19n);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="topmenu">menu</div>
<div id="homepage">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Suppose #homepage div is buried under several layers of div, do i have to make all the parent div's height to be 100% as well? In addition, is there a way to do the same thing without specifying the height of the menu as the height changes according to screen size.

Comment: Yep. You can only really use percentage height when the parent has height *explicitly* defined. `html` can use 100% height because it's a child of the window (in a loose sense), which is a defined height. The browser window *has*  to be some `x * y` pixels, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have edited the question to express this better. But am unable to get what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you work-out with the solution with current HTML - then its little difficult to get the background image spread across the screen.
2. In this case screen size (even though you keep it 100% height) will always be dependent on the content of `#homepage div`.
3. Best approach will be to include one more DIV within `#homepage div`. You can set the **'FIXED'** position for this newly introduced `div` and set it to the bottom of page. You may visit - [position div in the bottom of web page](http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/).
4. This way it will always ensure that your page will occupy whole web-page irrespective of content of the page and eventually **`background effect will appear for whole page`**.

Rest CSS and HTML coding could be the best `exercise` for you as you can do it yourself as well.

Please try this -

```
#your-div-id {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried your solution but it does not work. see https://jsfiddle.net/6x08snnt/18/

Comment: Please try with `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0`. Let me know if you still facing the problems.

Comment: doesn't work even though i change it. am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the calc function:
   If you want your deiv to have the browser height minus the menu height you write something like:

```
div {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}
```

If your menu height is 16 px.

Comment: Hi, what if the menu height vary according to screen size? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should either:
   1) Define the styles for the media query breakepoints; or
   2) Make a javascript/jQuery script that will be adjusting the height according to the height of the menu (any time that the height of the menu changes, the script will do the work for the height of the div)

But my suggestion is that you go with media query, because it's a simple problem.